GitHub Actions Sequential Merge Queue
I am trying to implement a merge queue where if a PR is merging to main, subsequent PRs merged to main will wait for the initial merge to complete before then merging each other PR one by one after one another. We are implementing this so that multiple PRs don't get bundled into one and pushed up, making it really hard to figure out which PR caused an outage if there is one.
I have my settings set up so that:
Build concurrency: 5
Merge limits: 1 or after 5 minutes
Maximum pull requests to merge: 1
I also have required checks on my post deployment tests which is the last stage of my CI pipeline.
I would assume that these settings mean that things can build in the merge queue, but only 1 PR can be merged at a time, giving me the funcitonality that I described previously. This does not seem to be the case. Am I missing something or is this just not possible to implement?

name: CI/CD
concurrency:
  group: ci-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: false

This setting prevents the CI from cancelling deployments meaning they'll go out 1 by 1 with the settings we have

That's unlikely possible using GitHub merge queue.
Mergify allows to do this by freezing the queue during the deployment and unfreezing it when you're deployment is done. This might be what look for to prevent merging code until it's completely deployed.
(disclaimer: I am part of the Mergify team).
